# CSS/Bootstrap How to have several cards of the same size?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, bootstrap-5

Can you tell me how I can get the same card size on all my lines?

Indeed the cards of the second line are taller. Would it be possible to use this height as a basis?

[image]

Here is my HTML code :

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
            <radio-button-square-card
                    *ngFor="let index of [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]"
                    [checked]="index === 5"
                    [index]="index"
                    [label]="' sonneries'"
                    [subtitle]="index === 5 ? '(par défaut)' : undefined"
                    class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-4 mb-1">
            </radio-button-square-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the HTML code of my component :

```html
<div class="card p-1 p-md-2 d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center h-100">
    <div class="flex-fill">
        <label [for]="index" [ngClass]="{'mb-0': subtitle}" class="standard font-weight-normal">
            {{index}}{{label}}
        </label>
        <p *ngIf="subtitle" class="small text-gray3 mt--1 mb-0">{{subtitle}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-0 p-0">
        <input (click)="selected.emit(index)" [checked]="checked" [id]="index"
               class="custom-control-input" name="customRadio" type="radio">
        <label [for]="index" class="custom-control-label" [style]="'position: relative !important'"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

For information I use 5 Bootstrap 5 and Angular 14

Comment: Isn't setting a height on cards working?

Comment: I don't want to fix the height in order to have a generic component

Answer (score 0):

You can pass element height to another with jQuery:

```
var h = $('#yellow').height();
$('.container > .row > p').css( "height", h );

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-cols-2 bg-success">
        <p class="bg-primary ">
        sth
        </p>
  <p class="bg-primary ">
    sth
  </p>
  <p class="bg-warning " id="yellow">
    sth<br>
    sth
  </p>
  <p class="bg-primary ">
    sth
  </p>
  <p class="bg-primary ">
    sth
  </p>
  <p class="bg-primary ">
    sth
  </p>
  <p class="bg-primary ">
    sth
  </p>
  <p class="bg-primary ">
    sth
  </p>
  
  </div>
</div>
```